# Gzip compress PDF files in Parse

Tags: javascript, pdf, parse-platform, compression, gzip

Is there a way to compress (gzip) PDF files in Parse? Also, is this a good idea - I checked by gzipping a text-based PDF file, and the file size reduced by around 30%.

Simplified code example --

```
<input type="file" id="pdfFileUpload">

var fileUploadControl = $("#pdfFileUpload")[0];
var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
// Compress file here
var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
// Or compress parseFile here

parseFile.save().then(function() {
  // The file has been saved to Parse.
}, function(error) {
  // The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
});
```

Here In this case, can we compress the file object by using the gzip compression method? What is the best way to do it?

Moreover, what is the recommended way to improve latency when uploading and downloading PDF files (~5 MB)?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you want to do this is the browser. The best solution is to rely on a client's browser, if you can afford it, to compress the PDF file, upload to Parse, download the compressed file from Parse and uncompress on the other client's browser. You can use Javascript implementation of zlib like [Pako](https://github.com/nodeca/pako) to do this in browser.
It seems that Parse backend is not yet delivering static content like files via CDNs, so if you really have concerns over network latency and delivery while you scale, you might want to host your files somewhere other than Parse.

Comment: Thanks for answering. You're right, I want to do it (the compression) in the browser. I'll check Pako out. I would prefer gzip compression, but thanks for the tip.
Updating the question title as well.